# WPF check if UIElement takes text input

Tags: wpf, uielement

Is there a way to check if a given `UIElement` takes text input? I see there's a `UIElement.TextInput` event handler so I could add/remove handlers, but of course I can't check if it is null (if at least one handler has been added to it).

I'm guessing it's not possible but maybe there's a workaround I don't know about.

Comment: You're trying to verify that it's a TextBox? Can you just look for a child named `PART_ContentHost`?

Comment: Why not looking at their types? there should be a finite number of UIElement types in your app which take text input, and they might act differently upon input.

Comment: @Brannon no, I wanted to check if the control handled TextInput (NumericUpDown, ComboBox, TextBox, etc).

Comment: @Bizhan you're right, that's the approach I already implemented. The problem is 1) performance (with 30 input controls on the list and a check for every keydown the impact is significative. 2) Mainteneability (keep the list up to date as new text taking controls are used by developers on the coming years).

Comment: a solution to both is to have a custom library for wpf elements. or you can add an attached property to the UIElement and set it "once" instead of on every key down.

Comment: @Bizhan That's what I end up doing, it works very well. Thanks